# Add new version of an item when deploying the content from JSS

Tags: jss

We are developing the JSS application in SSR headless mode. There will be more than 10 developers working at a time, when going through the options to deploy the content from JSS to Sitecore we noticed the below command,

jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary

This will install the content from JSS to Sitecore when our content item is in "Development Mode".

Referring https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/dev-workflows/code-first#content-workflow-and-developer-overwrite

So is there a way to add a new version whenever we deploy the app using the command "jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary"

I mean is there a way to implement as below
When executing the command "jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary"
 1. If any item which is new in JSS app, should get added to the Sitecore
 2. If any existing item [in "Published" state or no state selected] then create a new version for that item.
 3. If any item in other workflow states [not in final state] then overwrite the item

Any suggestion will help us to create a better deployment workflow.. Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to do this out of the box. It is probably possible with some customizations of the import pipeline, but generally speaking doing this seems like it might create an inordinate number of versions in Sitecore. This can significantly affect production performance if allowed to grow unchecked.

Comment: Thank You Kam, this helps us to decide the future workflow for our design..